Incorrect ID value being given in power automate
I have a flow which can be triggered using a button within a sharepoint list for a selected item to send an email. The button is made using conditional formatting.
Sometimes, sporadically, the flow will fail. On inspection it is always for the same reason when using Sharepoint Get Item: Item Not Found. This is because the ID being supplied by the manual trigger 'for this list item' is supplying the wrong ID. The ID is actually 27, but is being supplied as 100000027.
I have seen people encounter this problem before on other posts, but there has been no resolution to the problem.
Of course, I could check if the ID value contains '1000000', and if so remove it. But this doesn't seem satisfactory, and worry that this won't always work.
Does anyone have any ideas to help?
Image of the custom formatted sharepoint list within Teams:

Image of the relevant custom formatting for the flow button:

Image of the inputs given to the 'for selected list item' flow trigger with ID highlighted:

Image of the failed flow with incorrect ID highlighted:


I think this is a bug in SPO, and need to use a workaround to make the Power Automate to work properly.
I was able to reproduce by adding a list item in Edit in grid view. Initially, the IDs are generated with 10000000 prefix and stay that way even after exiting from the grid view editing. It allows to click the "Run Flow" button created with JSON formatting. Obviously, it's passing the wrong ID to the Flow. Only after reloading the view, the actual ID was showing.
See the screenshots below:


Wrong ID was passed to Power Automate


Odd, and interesting. In my application I didn't use 'edit with grid view' but it could be due to the custom formatting perhaps.

I've been having a bit of a play with different ways to input data and aren't finding a way to replicate my original problem consistently. Interesting to note about the grid view though.
